# Am I using the Input/Output Stream Library right?

Tags: c++, iostream

I am a newbie or noob if you prefer it that way in C++ programming and I'm trying to use `std::` because someone told me that is a good habit rather than putting in `using namespace std;` because it pollutes the global namespace. I'm not sure why `std::cin >> name;` from my code below produce an error `no operator '>>' matches these operands` below is the full source code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int x, y;
    std::string name;

    std::cin >> name;
    std::cin >> x;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You forgot this:

```
#include<string>
```

You're using `std::string` which is defined in the above header. You need to include it.

If you use anything from the Standard Library, whether it is container or algorithm, make sure that you have included the appropriate headers which define them. Standard library has lots of header files, especially for containers. As a general rule, each container is defined in its own header file.

Comment: I'm actually always confused about whether or not this is required. With my compiler (clang 3.1, on OS X) I can get away with only including `iostream` and not `string`. Is this simply because some C++ libraries include `string` from `iostream`?

Comment: @Xymostech yes, but don't count on it, it can change as soon as your compiler's implementation of the standard library is updated. Always include what you use and don't rely on implicit includes. Actually this applies to all libraries/headers, not only the standard library.

Comment: @Xymostech: You should not rely on that fact. Because it *can* change anytime. The Standard allows implementation to include other header files.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to

```
#include <string>
```

Also

```
#include <ios>
```

is not necessary.